# Javascript: How to get the class, from which a certain object was instantiated?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I have various ES6 classes, with inheritance. I need to be able to recognize the class, from which the object was instantiated.

I see that Javascript allows us to check, if an object is an instance of a certain calss, using the "instanceof" operator. The problem with this, is that it forces me to make multiple checks, for every possible relevant class.

Isn't there a way in JS to just get the class of the ojbect? For instance, in PHP there's a method for that:

> string get_class ([ object $object ] )

Can i achieve something similar in JS?

Comment: looking for typeof ? eg. `typeof 5`

Comment: if you have an instance `object` then `object.constructor` will yield the "class" of the object, which is actually a function in JS. for example "the name of the class" is `object.constructor.name` - the name of the initial function which in a `class` declaration is the class name

Comment: marmeladze: typeof returns just "object". Ovidiu Dolha: I see. Now i can extract the class name from the string that it returns.

Comment: "*I need to be able to recognize the class, from which the object was instantiated.*" - what do you need this for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an instance object then `object.constructor` will yield the "class" of the object, which is actually a function in JS.

For example "the name of the class" is `object.constructor.name` - the name of the initial function which in a class declaration is the class name

(Just realized this is actually an answer)

Comment: I see, thank you. boy oh boy is JS weird :D